# Clickable Three JS Convex Objects (once clicked reveals image)

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I adjusted an example from the three js website.

I'm looking for making the small floating objects have a click event.

The click event would trigger an image or video revealed on the larger convex shape in the center

**Concept + Images**

http://kevinwitkowski.tumblr.com/post/109592122645/workshop-update

[Working Sample](http://kevinwitkowski.ca/Flashback/3d/index.html)

Here is my current code.

```
            var container;

        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var mesh;
        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        // array of functions for the rendering loop
        var onRenderFcts= [];

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0xd6e3e8, 0.0030 );
            camera  = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000);
            camera.position.z = 0;
            controls    = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera)




            var light, object, materials;

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xe8dbd6 );
            light.position.set( -50, -80, -10 );
            scene.add( light );

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xd6dae8 );
            light.position.set( 20, 120, 1 );
            scene.add( light );

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xd6e8e4 );
            light.position.set( 0, 1, 30 );
            scene.add( light );

            var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/1.jpeg' );
            map.wrapS = map.wrapT = 
            THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            map.anisotropy = 16;

            var materials = [

                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } )

                //new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00000, shading: THREE.FlatShading, wireframe: true, transparent: false, opacity: 0.5} )

            ];



            // random convex 1

            points = [];
            for ( var i = 0; i < 30; i ++ ) {

                points.push( randomPointInSphere( 50 ) );

            }

            object = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( new THREE.ConvexGeometry( points ), materials );
            object.position.set( 0, 0, 0);
            scene.add( object );

            // random convex 2

            points = [];
            for ( var i = 0; i < 30; i ++ ) {

                points.push( randomPointInSphere( 15 ) );

            }

            object = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( new THREE.ConvexGeometry( points ), materials );
            object.position.set( 15, 50, -60 );
            scene.add( object );


            // random convex 3

            points = [];
            for ( var i = 0; i < 30; i ++ ) {

                points.push( randomPointInSphere( 15 ) );

            }

            object = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( new THREE.ConvexGeometry( points ), materials );
            object.position.set( 30, 10, 80 );
            scene.add( object );

            // random convex 4

            points = [];
            for ( var i = 0; i < 30; i ++ ) {

                points.push( randomPointInSphere( 8 ) );

            }

            object = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( new THREE.ConvexGeometry( points ), materials );
            object.position.set( -80, -50, 20 );
            scene.add( object );



            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setClearColor( 0xf5f5f5 );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );



            //




            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, true );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
            mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY );

        }

        //

        function randomPointInSphere( radius ) {

            return new THREE.Vector3(
                ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 1 * radius,
                ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 2 * radius,
                ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 2 * radius
            );

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            render();


        }

        function render() {

            var timer = Date.now() * 0.00005;

            camera.position.x = Math.cos( timer ) * 300;
            camera.position.z = Math.sin( timer ) * 300;

            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            for ( var i = 0, l = scene.children.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

                var object = scene.children[ i ];

                object.rotation.x = timer * 1;
                object.rotation.y = timer * 3;

            }

            // handle window resize
    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight )
    camera.aspect   = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()     
    }, true)


            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
var lastTimeMsec= null
requestAnimationFrame(function animate(nowMsec){
    // keep looping
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    // measure time
    lastTimeMsec    = lastTimeMsec || nowMsec-1000/60
    var deltaMsec   = Math.min(200, nowMsec - lastTimeMsec)
    lastTimeMsec    = nowMsec
    // call each update function
    onRenderFcts.forEach(function(onRenderFct){
        onRenderFct(deltaMsec/1000, nowMsec/1000)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way of doing this is using a THREE.Raycaster and THREE.Projector to cast a ray from the camera through space, then finding if an object intersects with this ray.

See this example: http://soledadpenades.com/articles/three-js-tutorials/object-picking/

Thankfully, others have implemented libraries such as ObjectControls: https://github.com/cabbibo/ObjectControls

This allows you to directly attach hover or select events to meshes and it will just work.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateMultiMaterialObject` method creates an object3D, so when you click, it is necessary to specify the second parameter (`recursion`) = `true`:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true );

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

    intersects[ 0 ].object.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );

}
```